# Very High wait time?

Tags: sql-server

We currently have one production SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition , running on Windows server 2008R2 standard ( 32 GB RAM , 16 cpu). there are around 22,000 connection. the Max worker thread is setting to 0.

when i am running this query

```
SELECT SUM(current_workers_count) as [Current worker thread] FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers
```

i am getting always around 780. this system has a high wait time.

[image]

also when i query this

```
SELECT  *
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC
```

[image]

[image]

I need help what is wrong? is this hardware issue or application issue

Comment: What exactly has a high wait time? Forget about the output from sys.dm_os_wait_stats for moment, a lot of which is completely irrelevant to end user queries (and that you can do anything about anyway - you're not filtering out any of the queue/timer waits, for example, which are going to be high by definition, but they don't affect your end users). You're always going to have a top wait, that doesn't mean it's a (or the) problem. So, are users actually complaining about slowness? In which queries exactly? Have you tried to determine what *those* queries are waiting on?

Comment: Isn't 22,000 connection cumulative that your screenshot is showing ? Run sp_whoisactive and see whats going on on the server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the  expensive queries mainly have SOS_SCHEDUALED_ YIELD or IO_COMPLETION .. users are not complaining so far .. but we are expecting the number of connection to doubled so i need to be ready

Comment: First thing I would suggest at a high level is increase cost threshold for parallelism. I assume it's at the default 5, and from the looks of your waits you have a lot of queries going parallel that probably shouldn't/

Comment: With `threadpool` waits being so high, maybe you should consider upping the `max worker threads` option:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @AaronBertrand what should i do to avoid queries going parallel? also what should i set the  cost threshold for parallelism

Comment: @MaxVernon it is already set to 0 which make SQL server use the max available

Comment: I typically recommend changing it to 40 or 50. That may not be the ideal setting for your environment, and there's no way for me to pull the perfect number out of my rear, but is probably a good start.

Comment: @AaronBertrand .. i changed the cost threshold for parallelism and i can see there is great improvement
May i ask you what is Preemptive mode mean? is this sign for lake of resources

Comment: Preemptive means SQL Server is giving control over to the operating system to do something. It has nothing to do directly with resources, it's just a way to characterize what the code is doing.

Comment: @sebeid 0 indicates SQL SERVER should auto-configure - you can override that value, and probably should if you have 20,000 connections.

Comment: @MaxVernon what should be the value ?

Comment: According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 with 16 processors, SQL Server will be using a maximum of 704 worker threads.  You might try bumping that up to 960 or 1024; either way you'll want to ensure you monitor closely prior to and after changing the setting to see what the effect is on *your server*.